# Sites where the badge symbol matches or resembles the badge name

Tags: discussion, badges

Each site has its own symbols for badges. Here on Meta, it's a dot (super imaginative, gang!) while on Travel, it's a map marker. On Academia, it's a mortarboard - the hat you wear when you graduate from some academic institutions. So when you earn Mortarboard, you get an actual mortarboard! (Which you also get when you earn any other badge, but that's not my point.)

Are there any other combinations of badge and site where the site-wide badge symbol is particularly appropriate for a particular badge name?

Answer (score 6):

The [shield badges on Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/badges) and any of the [Citizen Patrol](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol), [Deputy](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/badges/66/deputy), [Marshall](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/badges/79/marshal), [Constable](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/badges/1132/constable) or [Sheriff](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/badges/1133/sheriff) badges:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

The diamond on [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) fits with all of the [moderation badges](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/badges) -- Citizen Patrol/Deputy/Marshall, Custodian/Reviewer/Steward/Proofreader, Critic, Synonymizer/Tag Editor/Research Assistant, and many others.

[image: screen shot of some badges]

Answer (score 5):

[Enlightened](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/enlightened) on [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/) is pretty neat with its lightbulb.

Answer (score 1):

Some tag badges happen to match the site icon.

- Mathematics: [triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/triangle) ([bronze](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/296/triangle) only)
- Science Fiction & Fantasy: [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/star-wars) ([ish](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/976/design-for-science-fiction-fantasy#comment1980_983)) ([bronze](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/star-wars), [silver](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81/star-wars), [gold](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/106/star-wars))
- Stack Overflow: [dot](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dot) ([bronze](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2221/dot))

Many more may be earned some day:

- Bicycles: [gears](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tags/gears)
- Database Administrators: [foreign-key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/foreign-key) (?); [primary-key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/primary-key) (?); [natural-key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/natural-key) (?)
- Game Development: [hexagon](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/hexagon)
- Geographic Information Systems: [markers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/markers)
- Home Improvement: [screws](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tags/screws)
- Mathematics: [magic-square](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/magic-square) (?) (silver only)
- Physics: [point-particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/point-particle)
- Unix & Linux: [home](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/home); [tilda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/tilda)

And of course:

- Meta: [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/badges) ([bronze](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/94/badges), [silver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/121/badges))